# Set the Network Service Tier at the resource level for new Clusters

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm working on a hobby Kubernetes project on GKE that I want to keep cheap  (standard tier only).

I would like to craft a `gcloud container clusters create` command that creates a cluster that will always create network interfaces on the standard tier, even when the default network tier for my project is premium.

I'm using [Network Service Tiers](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-tier/tiers/details) to reveal what resources are created on each tier for each resource type.

My best guess is that because network tiers are still in beta, that the reserved key `instance-template` (undocumented) holds the secrets on how my network interfaces are created.

Answer (score 0):

instance-template is not exposed because GKE manages the instances.

The other [objects affected by network service tiers](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/apis), are basically addresses,  forwarding rules, and project. I cannot find a way to associate an address with a cluster. A (regional, network) load balancer for a forwarding rule may be additional cost.

Either set it at the project level (you can have several projects), or use premium tier.

Comment: I don't see how GKE managing the instance would prevents GKE from accepting a user provided instance-template.   The reason instance-template is not exposed appears to be because Google did not write it that way.

Comment: By specifying "even when the default network tier for my project is premium", I had hoped it to be understood that there was not an issue when the default network tier for my project was not premium.  To be more explicit, I want to craft a single idempotent `clusters create` command that would always give me the cheaper cluster without always having to check the current state of the project (idiot proof).  Also,  @john-mahowald's suggestion to use premium tier is exactly what I was asking to avoid.